# While statement skips fist row

Tags: php, database, function, if-statement, while-loop

I think that because of the if statement, the while statment skips the first one.

But i need the IF and i need the WHILE.

here is my code:

```
            if($row_antwoorden_select = mysqli_fetch_array($results_antwoorden_select)){
            while($row_antwoorden_select = mysqli_fetch_array($results_antwoorden_select)){
                $antwoorden .= "".$row_antwoorden_select['naam']."".$row_antwoorden_select['methode']." <a href='".$row_antwoorden_select['url']."'>Open</a><br>";  
                $once_info = "<h4>Antwoorden:</h4>".$select_menu."<br>";
            }
        }
```

Comment: This is a common mistake. Are you running the `if` to test if the query returned rows? That is unnecessary because the `while` loop won't run if it did not.  You need to eliminate the `if`.  If there is a different purpose for the `if` than evident with this code, perhaps you can use `mysqli_num_rows()` instead.

Comment: Your query don't have `num_rows`

Comment: You don't need the `if` since the `while` loop condition is the same as an `if` that runs for each iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using `$row_antwoorden_select = mysqli_fetch_array($results_antwoorden_select)` in your `if` statement which is absolutely wrong because you must check available number of rows in your table using `num_rows` function You should try this will resolve your issue

```
if($results_antwoorden_select->num_rows > 0){
    while($row_antwoorden_select = mysqli_fetch_array($results_antwoorden_select)){
    $antwoorden = "".$row_antwoorden_select['naam']."".$row_antwoorden_select['methode']." <a href='".$row_antwoorden_select['url']."'>Open</a><br>";  
    $once_info = "<h4>Antwoorden:</h4>".$select_menu."<br>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Please do add some explanation

Comment: Ok let me do it

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your `if` statement is just checking to see if there are results from the query. If that's true and you really want to keep the `if` statement, you could update it to use [`mysqli_num_rows()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php) instead:

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($results_antwoorden_select) > 0) {
    while($row_antwoorden_select = mysqli_fetch_array($results_antwoorden_select)){
        $antwoorden .= "".$row_antwoorden_select['naam']."".$row_antwoorden_select['methode']." <a href='".$row_antwoorden_select['url']."'>Open</a><br>";  
        $once_info = "<h4>Antwoorden:</h4>".$select_menu."<br>";
    }
}
```

*Note:* `mysqli_fetch_array()` will return `null` if there aren't any results, so technically just eliminating the `if` block entirely will let your sample code work perfectly fine.

Alternatively, if you *really* want to keep the `mysqli_fetch_array()` in the `if` block, you could update your loop to be a `do/while` instead:

```
if($row_antwoorden_select = mysqli_fetch_array($results_antwoorden_select)) {
    do {
        $antwoorden .= "".$row_antwoorden_select['naam']."".$row_antwoorden_select['methode']." <a href='".$row_antwoorden_select['url']."'>Open</a><br>";  
        $once_info = "<h4>Antwoorden:</h4>".$select_menu."<br>";
    } while($row_antwoorden_select = mysqli_fetch_array($results_antwoorden_select));
}
```